# While calling RcmdrPlugin.BCA I get this error message: object 'importRODBCtable' not found

Tags: r, plugins, analytics, rodbc

I call `library('RcmdrPlugin.BCA')` but unfortunately i get error message like this:

> object 'importRODBCtable' not found

Answer (score 0):

Before `library('RcmdrPlugin.BCA')` have you executed `install.packages("RcmdrPlugin.BCA")`?

If you did it, the problem may be the version: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcmdrPlugin.BCA/index.html

You have to work with R version above 3.0.0. and Rcmdr above 2.1-0.